# reported speech with past perfect?

Tags: grammar

Please take a look,at this sentence

I met him last summer and I asked him what he was doing over  here and he said he'd come over to release a single and I thought.....

" He said he had come over here" is reported sppeech , but is it a backshift of "I came over" or did he answer "I had come over"

I think it is not a backshift as the man had arrived before the narrator met him
Am I right ? If I am wrong let me know why

Comment: Whether it's a backshift or not, he had come over there before he said it, right?

Answer (score 1):

The past perfect can be reported speech of the *present perfect*.

"He said he had come over" sounds like  a backshift of

"I have come over to release a single."

If the original was in the simple past,

"I came over,"

it is an option to backshift the simple past, but [it is not a requirement](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/51504/reported-speech-and-past-perfect/51510#51510).

Comment: There's also a useful (it seems to me) table [here](http://www.englisch-hilfen.de/en/grammar/reported.htm). Section 4.

Answer (score 0):

It would be a backshift of "I came over". If we rewrite the sentence in present tense, it would look something like this.

> "So, what are you doing over here?" I asked.
>
> "**I came over** to release a single." he replied.

If he had said "I **had** come over...", that would be [past perfect tense](http://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/pastperfect.html), which implies that he came over and then he left. When you say

> I asked him what he was doing **here**...

that implies you are *both* **here**, or at least, you were both there at the time you asked him the question. If you are both here at the moment, he couldn't have left yet.

Also, this is unrelated to your main question, but the sentence you used is a [run-on-sentence.](http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/runons.htm) Here is one of many different ways you could rewrite this.

> When I met him last summer, I asked him what he was doing over here. He said he'd come over to release a single. I thought...

Comment: So why did the narrator backshift was it necessary?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know. Having grown up speaking English, my test for whether or not something is correct is mainly just saying it out loud and seeing if it sounds right or not. You ELL's ask a lot of good questions, and I feel like I learn just as much from trying to answer a question as you guys do getting your question answered. You could check out δοῦλος's link.

Comment: Or [this](http://www.englisch-hilfen.de/en/grammar/reported.htm) link.

Comment: There is no run-on sentence. The clauses are connected with *and.*